# Cannot launch AVD in Emulator [Android Studio 2.2]

Tags: android

I'd installed HAXM emulator but am still getting the problem in Running AVD.
provide me a solution for this error?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you have an incomplete installation of the Android SDK. Perhaps something failed when Android Studio tried downloading and unpacking it.

Comment: So should i re-install Android Studio ? @CommonsWare

Comment: That would be one possibility. Since I do not know how you got in this state in the first place, I do not know whether uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio will help or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should copy and paste the error message here. You should also include a description of what you did that caused the error.

Comment: Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Couldn't find file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\ca-bundle.pem
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: libcurl is not initialized. Bailing.
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'      //This is the error i got while running emulator @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Use the edit link at the bottom of your question rather than posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

your android SDK has an incomplete update , specifically the HAXM installer for running the emulator is corrupted some how.

You need to reinstall the required platforms and the system images for those platforms 
Go to the **local.properties** and change the sdk path to the new sdk (if downloaded from scratch), otherwise it will work if the current sdk is updated perfectly.